# migrating to AFNetworking 3.0 in objective C

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-3

The code if for checking login data with mysql database using php. the code was working with AFNetworking 2.0 but not I'm migrating to AFNetworking 3.0.
I modified the code according to the GitHub documentation.

however I got this error!

[image: this is the error image, not sure what it is, and no error is showing on the code!]

if I remove this code, the errors goes away!

```
  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     // dismiss uiviewController after data loading is done
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
     //NSLog(@"success");
     NSDictionary *temp = [[NSDictionary alloc]init ];

     temp = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
     if(temp.count > 0)
     {
         NSDictionary *TeacherInfo = responseObject[0];
         TeacherName = TeacherInfo[@"Teacher_Name"];
         TeacherID = TeacherInfo[@"Teacher_NO"];
         IsUserAdmin = TeacherInfo[@"IsAdmin"];
         TeacherSubject1 = TeacherInfo[@"Subject1No"];
         TeacherSubject2 = TeacherInfo[@"Subject2No"];
         TeacherSubject3 = TeacherInfo[@"Subject3No"];
         TeacherSubject4 = TeacherInfo[@"Subject4No"];

         //  ViewController *Navigate = (ViewController *)
         //  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChoicesViewController"];;
         // [self presentViewController:Navigate animated:YES completion:nil];

     }
     else
     {
         UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"wrong user name or password"
                                                                        message:@"please enter correct data"
                                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

         UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

         [alert addAction:defaultAction];
         [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
 }
 // if failed to connect
     failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"connection error"
                                                                    message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

     UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

     [alert addAction:defaultAction];
     [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't use dependency manager like CocoaPods. Probably you add AFNetworking library manually. You must check your target name in 
`Show the File in inspector` for the `.m` file of `AFHTTPSessionManager`.

[image]

Comment: I added the folder of afnetworking manually, copy paste, as suggested in a tutorial I found online. I checked the folder for the afhttpsessionmanager.m and it is there.

Comment: First, the afhttpsessionmanager.m file exists but you make sure to click on Target membership TargetName checkbox according to the pic on my post.
If your issue still exists remove all of files AFNetworking (ver 2 and 3) and add again ver 3.
As I said checked .m files for your target.
finally, I highly recommend you to use dependency management such as CocoaPods.

Comment: thank you, I will look up this CocoaPods, use it and see what happens from their on...

Comment: @jack You're welcome! It would be great if you use voting when your problem is solved. ;)